# How to convert a binary number into integer in lua

Tags: lua

i have a array of 1 and 0,

for example 10110

```
values = {1,0,1,1,0}
max = 0
for value = 6,1,-1 do
  max = max + 2*index*value
end
```

but how could get the index of the array in order to calculate the max

Comment: `values = {1,0,1,1,0}; n = tonumber(table.concat(values), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
values = {1,0,1,1,0}
max = 0
for index = 1,#values,1 do
   max = max + 2^(#values-index)*values[index]
end 

print(max)
```